# Commit to a specific branch of a github repository in Rstudio

Tags: git, github, rstudio

I want to commit a file (rmarkdown) to a specific branch of a repository linked to an r project using `git`. The rproject I have is linked to the overall repository ([https://github.com/[repository_name]](https://github.com/%5Brepository_name%5D)), but for this specific file I want to commit it to a specific branch of that repository ([https://github.com/[repository_name]/[branch_name]](https://github.com/%5Brepository_name%5D/%5Bbranch_name%5D)). Is there a way to commit the file/push changes to this specific branch, instead of just sending it to the main repository? Or do I need to reset the origin of my r project every single time I want to commit to a different branch?

Comment: `https://github.com/repo_name/branch_name` is not how you access branches in GitHub. Anyways, you can switch branches with `git checkout branch_name` (add `-b` for creating a new branch) and commit there. Note that commits are associated with branches (a branch refers to a commit and commits have a history) and files are included in commits. Files are not directly associated with branches.